# Combining multiple templates in each other

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

How can I combine multiple types in one function like

```
template < typename T1 >
template < typename T2 >
T2 average( T1 v1, T1 v2, T1 v3 )
{
    T averageValue;
    cout<<"after averageValue; v1: "<<typeid(v1).name()
        <<" v2: "<<typeid(v2).name()
        <<" v3: "<<typeid(v3).name()
        <<" averageValue: "<<typeid(averageValue).name();
    averageValue =(v1+v2+v3)/.3;
    cout<<"\nAfter averageValue =(v1+v2+v3)/3; averageValue: "<<typeid(averageValue).name();
    return averageValue;
};
```

I know that the code won't compile but I want to know if there is any way to do something like that

Comment: `template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>`?

Comment: If the operation `(v1+v2+v3)/3` is well defined, then you can do that. What are the types `T1`, `T2`, and `T3` you were typically expecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++17 you can use a [variadic template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) with a [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) in conjunction with the [`sizeof...`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof...) operator:

```
template<typename... Args>
auto average(Args&&...args)
{
    return (args + ...) / double(sizeof...(args));
}
```

Comment: why not `const Args&` if you are not going to forward args?

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple template arguments

```
template< typename T1, typename T2>
T2 average(T1 v1, T1 v2, T1 v3){
// stuff
}
```

Just make sure to declare `averageValue` as `T2`. Of course, this will only work if `(v1+v2+v3)/3` is defined and can be converted to `T2`.

Comment: `template<typename T1, typename T2>
T2 average(T1 v1, T1 v2, T1 v3){return (v1+v2+v3)/.3;};` But when I used it as average(1,2,3) the compiler said  'average': no matching overloaded function found  'T2 average(T1,T1,T1)': could not deduce template argument for 'T2'   note: see declaration of 'average'

Comment: @AsmM How is the compiler supposed to know what T2 should be in that case? Try using `average<int, float>(1,2,3)`. (If you change your template declaration's start to `template<typename T2, typename T1>`, you could potentially simplify the call to `average<float>(1,2,3)`.)

Comment: You can also assing default template arguments `template< typename T1, typename T2 = float >`